# How to extract specific elements from fetch .text() function and render it in html

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

code can be tested using "user javascript and css" chrome extension on this url  https://www.pamono.com/furniture.

in fetch function I need to render specific elements from products page to display on main page as a quick view popup.
whenever I try to displays any element it renders as a [object NodeList]
// Update : it renders [object NodeList] because i was getting a carousel which includes lot of images the solution was to loop if through carousel images and get it.
the problem now that it imports the same images each time

```js
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("product-card");
for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  const quickView = document.createElement('button');
  const quickViewText = document.createTextNode('Quick View');
  quickView.appendChild(quickViewText);
  quickView.className = "view";
  const quickViewBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("view");
  const gallery = document.createElement('div');
  gallery.className = "gallery";
  cards[i].appendChild(gallery);
  cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let targetLink = this.querySelector(".link-wrapper");
    console.log(targetLink);
    //continue import elements from each url
    var responseClone; // 1
    fetch(targetLink)
      .then(function(response) {
        responseClone = response.clone(); // 2
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Do something with data
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log((data.status));

      }, function(rejectionReason) { // 3
        console.log('Error parsing JSON from response:', rejectionReason, responseClone); // 4
        responseClone.text() // 5
          .then(function(html) {
            // Convert the HTML string into a document object
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

            // Get the image file
    // Get the carousel div
    var img = doc.querySelector('.product-name');
    console.log(img);
    gallery.appendChild(img);
    var carouselItems=doc.querySelectorAll('.thumb');
    for( thumb of carouselItems){
    gallery.appendChild(thumb);
    }
            //   console.log('Received the following instead of valid JSON:', bodyText); // 6
          });
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: You can make a `documentFragment` containing the response text, then use DOM functions to extract the desired elements from it.

Comment: didn't work, I tried querySelector instead of querySelectorAll as I am requesting for 1 element but it didn't work as well.

Comment: `querySelector` returns a DOM element, not HTML. So just do `gallery.appendChild(img)`

Comment: @Barmar yeah I tried that but it gives me this error : `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`

Comment: Did you check that `doc.querySelector()` returned something? What does `console.log(img)` show?

Comment: Shows null, I don't know why

Comment: Can you show an example of the `html`?

Comment: this is the page I am working on https://www.pamono.com/furniture. it's a web page i don't have access to html as it's an evaluation task, I am using"user javascript and css" chrome extension, you can paste my code to the extension and choose the web page to be https://www.pamono.com/furniture.

Comment: The rendered html would be available in the browser, even if it's not your webpage.

Comment: ah ok I thought you want to see the whole html code, well I have updated the code above and the rendered html is an empty div if I try to get a big element like a carousel, it only allows small elements like h1.
on the above code you will notice that I looped inside the carousel images to get it one by one in this case it gets the same collection of images each time.
It would be highly appreciated if you can paste my code inside "user javascript and css"  chrome extension to see the whole thing more clear

Comment: `fetch(targetLink)` doesn't make any sense. The argument to `fetch()` must be a URL, but `targetLink` is a DOM element. Did you mean `fetch(targetLink.href)`?

Comment: oh yes sorry for missing that while pasting, anyways it shows the same problem trying to render a carousel.